# What constructor should be called in return statement with curly braces?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

Consider the following code:

```
struct NonMovable {
  NonMovable() = default;
  NonMovable(const NonMovable&) = default;
  NonMovable(NonMovable&&) = delete;
};

NonMovable f() {
  NonMovable nonMovable;
  return {nonMovable};
  //return NonMovable(nonMovable);
}

int main() {}
```

GCC and Clang compile that code without errors, i.e. copy constructor was called when curly braces are used. But msvc reject it https://godbolt.org/z/49onKj with the error:

> ```
> error C2280: 'NonMovable::NonMovable(NonMovable &&)': attempting to reference a deleted function
> ```

When I specify explicit call to copy constructor (since `nonMovable` is not an rvalue) then mvsc accepts the code.

Who's correct? What type of constructor should be called in `return {var};` statement there?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that msvc is in the wrong.

Comment: See [list_initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) #8

Comment: I think MSVC implements wrongly [Automatic_move_from_local_variables_and_parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return#Automatic_move_from_local_variables_and_parameters).

Comment: I assume the context of the question is related to Sy's [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/guaranteed-copy-elision-does-not-elide-copies/).

Comment: I'm not a language-lawyer anymore, hung up my spurs in 2010.  I think MSVC's CL.EXE is in the wrong.  If you comment out the deleted move-ctor entirely, it no longer participates in consideration.  (An explicitly deleted constructor still participates in constructor consideration, whereas an implicitly deleted constructor does not.)  Given the C++17 new-fangled *deferred temporary materialization*, I'm not surprised that there may be compiler bugs.  Microsoft didn't finish C++98 support until 2018.  They've got a lot of irons in the fire.

Comment: @Eljay _If you comment out the deleted move-ctor entirely, it no longer participates in consideration. (An explicitly deleted constructor still participates in constructor consideration, whereas an implicitly deleted constructor does not.)_ Why implicitly declared move ctor is implicitly deleted here? Implicitly declared move ctor is just so trivial that you don't see its call in assembly listing. Remove `= default` and `= delete` from copy and move ctors, respectively, and you'll see MSVC producing call to the move ctor.

Comment: Regardless of the compiler bug, don’t explicitly delete move constructors like this.  Since copying is a valid implementation of moving, `T(std::move(t))` in generic code should fall back to copy, not fail outright.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer • You are correct, I was mistaken.  I was thinking of the `NonMovable(const NonMovable&) { }` case which would prevent a synthesized move constructor.  But that is not the same as the `NonMovable(const NonMovable&) = default;` case, which does not impact whether-or-not a synthesized move constructor is synthesized.

Comment: @Eljay Isn't `NonMovable(const NonMovable&) = default;` a user-*declared* copy ctor? It prevents implicit declaration of move ctor. But no move ctor ≠ implicitly deleted move ctor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is quite some implementation confusion regarding return value copy elision and temporary materialization. To begin with, let's have a look at the OP's example slightly modified to not use the braced-init-list in the return statement:

```
// Program (A1)
struct NonMovable {
  NonMovable() = default;
  NonMovable(const NonMovable&) = default;
  NonMovable(NonMovable&&) = delete;  // #1
};

NonMovable f() {
  NonMovable nonMovable;
  return nonMovable;  // #2
                      // GCC, Clang: OK
                      // MSVC: Error (use of deleted function)
}

int main() {}
```

`#1` formally provides an *explicitly-deleted* definition for the move constructor, meaning the move constructor will participate in overload resolution, and its lack of a non-deleted definition will have no effect on the result of overload resolution.

Now, as per [[class.copy.elision]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.elision#3), overload resolution for the copy-init context of #2 is (possibly) two-phase, starting to look for an ctor overload as if the object were designated by an rvalue:

> In the following copy-initialization contexts, a move operation might be used instead of a copy operation:
>
> (3.1) If the expression in a return statement is a (possibly parenthesized) id-expression that names an object with automatic storage duration declared in the body or parameter-declaration-clause of the innermost enclosing function or lambda-expression, or [...]
>
> overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy **is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue. If** the first overload resolution **fails or was not performed**, or if the type of the first parameter of the selected constructor is not an rvalue reference to the object's type (possibly cv-qualified), **overload resolution is performed again, considering the object as an lvalue.**

The key here being that the second phase is only performed if the first phase overload resolution *fails* (or was not performed). In the example above, the first phase overload resolution will find the deleted move ctor, and the second phase will not be performed. Thus, solely based on [class.copy.elision]/3, one would argue that program (A) is ill-formed.

On the other hand, all non-deleted constructors in `NonMovable` are trivial, meaning we may turn to [[class.temporary]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.temporary#3),

> When an object of class type X is passed to or **returned from a function**, **if each** copy constructor, move constructor, and destructor of X **is either trivial or deleted**, and X has **at least one non-deleted copy or move constructor**, implementations are permitted to create a temporary object to hold the function parameter or result object. The temporary object is constructed from the function argument or return value, respectively, and **the** function's parameter or **return object is initialized as if by using the non-deleted trivial constructor to copy the temporary** (**even if that constructor** is inaccessible or **would not be selected by overload resolution** to perform a copy or move of the object).

Which would arguably overrule the fact that [class.copy.elision]/3 would *otherwise* reject the program.

Before going into what the compilers actually do here, consider a slightly modified version of program (A1) above:

```
// Program (A2)
struct NonMovable {
  NonMovable() {};
  NonMovable(const NonMovable&) {};
  NonMovable(NonMovable&&) = delete;  // #1
};

// ... as above
```

where the default and copy ctors have now been made non-trivial as they are user-provided.

Then:

- Clang 11: accepts both (A1) and (A2) for C++14 through C++20
- Clang 13: rejects both (A1) and (A2) for C++14 through C++20
- GCC 10: accepts both (A1) and (A2) for C++14 through C++20
- GCC 11: accepts both (A1) and (A2) for C++14 through C++17; rejects both for C++20
- MSVC: rejects both (A1) and (A2) for C++14 through C++20

If we tweak program (A1) and (A2) but wrapping the return object in braces,

```
// ... as above
return {nonMovable};
```

denoting the corresponding programs as (B1) and (B2), then:

- Clang 11: accepts both (B1) and (B2) for C++14 through C++20
- Clang 13: accepts both (B1) and (B2) for C++14 through C++20
- GCC 10: accepts both (B1) and (B2) for C++14 through C++20
- GCC 11: accepts both (B1) and (B2) for C++14 through C++20
- MSVC: rejects both (B1) and (B2) for C++14 through C++20

---

> Who's correct? What type of constructor should be called in `return {var};` statement there?

To wrap up and answer the OP's original question, MSVC is wrong to reject (B1) and (B2), as [class.copy.elision]/3, particularly /3.1, does not apply when the expression in a return statement is a braced-init-list, even if it wraps a named object with automatic storage duration. This case is simply braced-copy-init, and the copy constructor shall be the best viable function resulting from overload resolution.

The implementation variance for (A1) and (A2) likely relates to [P1825R0: Merged wording for P0527R1 and P1155R3 (more implicit moves)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1825r0.html), which would explain why both GCC 11 and Clang 13 now rejects both (A1) and (A2) for C++20, and we may moreover note that [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) and [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) particularly marks P1825R0 as implemented in release 11 and 13, respectively.

I do not understand, however, why Clang 13 also seems to have backported this, particularly rejecting (A1) and (A2) also for C++14 and C++17. We may note that Clang (even in earlier version) also rejects the example of [[diff.cpp17.class]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/diff.cpp17.class#3) (added to the C++20 standard as part of P1825R0, highlighting a compatibility change from C++17) in C++14 and C++17 which is arguably a Clang bug. I'm speculating that the backporting rejection of (A1) and (A2) is unintentional.

Comment: _the expression in a return statement is a braced-init-list_ Do you mean _the operand_? Because braced-init-list is not an expression.