# Meaning of `{}` for return expression

Tags: c++, return, list-initialization

I found by accident that the following compiles:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class A{
    int i{};
    std::string s{};
    public:
        A(int _i, const std::string& _s) : i(_i), s(_s) {
            puts("Called A(int, const std::string)");
        }

};

A foo(int k, const char* cstr){
    return {k, cstr};           // (*)
}

int main(){
    auto a = foo(10, "Hi!");
    return 0;
}
```

The line of interest is (*). I guess the function `foo` is equivalent to:

```cpp
A foo(int k, const char* str){
    return A(k, cstr);
}
```

However, is there a special name for this mechanism in (*)? Or is it just the simple fact that the compiler knows which constructor to call due to the return type?

Comment: It's known as [copy list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), it's a convenient way to return stuff.

Comment: It could depend upon the particular C++ standard you refer to. See [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and read [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) or some newer C++ standard.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. @NathanPierson Feel free to post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Note that in recent C++ Standards the compiler will perform (and usually perform in older Standards) some pretty slick magic ([Copy Elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)) to make this a particularly efficient way to return an object.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66707854/3240681)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`return {k, cstr};` means that `{k, cstr}` is the initializer for the return value. Also, it indicates "return an object of the function's return type initialized with `k` and `cstr`, which means that the exact behavior depends on the returned object's type".

The return value can be initialized in two different ways:

- `return A(k, cstr);` - the return value is [copy-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) from `k, cstr`
- `return {k, cstr};` - the return value is  [copy list initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)  from the class `A`.

Answer (score 16):

This is a specific form of [copy list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

See number 8 on the list in that reference:

> List initialization is performed in the following situations:
>
> ...
>
> copy-list-initialization (both explicit and non-explicit constructors are considered, but only non-explicit constructors may be called)
>
> ...
>
> 8. in a return statement with braced-init-list used as the return expression and list-initialization initializes the returned object